# Is there a way to separate values like "csv" strings on multiple columns on Redshift SQL?

Tags: sql, csv, amazon-redshift, columnsorting

For example: if I do a `select preferences from stores` I get this outcome:

```
|preferences                                                           |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|"debit_rate"=>"0.00", "credit_rate_1"=>"0.01", "credit_rate_2"=>"0.02"|
|"debit_rate"=>"0.03", "credit_rate_1"=>"0.04", "credit_rate_2"=>"0.05"|
|"debit_rate"=>"0.06", "credit_rate_1"=>"0.07", "credit_rate_2"=>"0.08"|
|"debit_rate"=>"0.09", "credit_rate_1"=>"0.10", "credit_rate_2"=>"0.11"|
```

Is there a way for me to get this outcome?

| debit_rate | credit_rate_1 | credit_rate_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00 | 0.01 | 0.02 |
| 0.03 | 0.04 | 0.05 |
| 0.06 | 0.07 | 0.08 |
| 0.09 | 0.10 | 0.11 |

Comment: Looks like you could do it with a couple of passes of [split_part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html)

Comment: @Andrew with your suggestion I came up with this:

,replace(split_part(split_part(preferences,'=>',2),',',1),'"','')::decimal(18,2) debit_rate
,replace(split_part(split_part(preferences,'=>',3),',',1),'"','')::decimal(18,2) credit_rate_1
,replace(split_part(split_part(preferences,'=>',4),',',1),'"','')::decimal(18,2) credit_rate_2

and it gave me the expected results, but I found it looked like bad code, maybe is there another, more ellegant way to do this? thanks anyways

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  It's not exactly pretty code, but you are doing 3 steps here, two splits and a cast.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are small change from making these sting into valid json.  redshift has json functions that will allow for more intelligent parsing of these strings.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html

If you just change the '=>' to ':' and wrap the whole thing in curly braces '{}' you should be there.

Then you can cast these strings to be type SUPER and access the data by key value.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html